# How can I add a int level variable to decide from what level to start getting the objects? And what colliders should I add to them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetComponents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform parent;
    public List<GameObject> allObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        string path = "e:/colliders.txt";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);

        allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();

        Transform[] allChildren = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
        {
            var colliders = child.GetComponents<Collider>();

            int length = colliders.Length;

            if (length == 0)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - No Colliders", child.name));
            }
            else
            {
                //composes a list of the colliders types, this will print what you want e.g. "Wall1 - BoxCollider, MeshCollider"

                string colliderTypes = string.Empty;

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    colliderTypes = string.Format("{0}{1}", colliderTypes, colliders[i].GetType().Name);

                    if (i != (length - 1))
                    {
                        colliderTypes = string.Format("{0}, ", colliderTypes);
                    }
                }
                //writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", child.name, colliderTypes));
            }
        }

        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

In this case I'm getting only objects without colliders. And then I want to add to each object a collider. But since there are so much objects I want to add to each one of them a collider that will prevent from the player character to move through them. I'm not sure if just to add to them a mesh collider or some other collider/s?

And how can I set a level to start getting the objects from ?

For example I have this structure :

```
Parent
 Child 1
 Child 2
 Child 3
 Child 4
```

Now level 0 is the parent level 1 is the childs 1 to 4. But in each child 1,2,3,4 there are many more children in many levels(trees).

I want fro example to get the transforms childs form level 1 so it will not include the parent and the childs 1,2,3,4 as objects without colliders.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this
1.Check if the parent of the child is the one you want.

```
foreach (Transform child in allChildren){ 
  if(child.parent == parent){
   //Add colliders}
```

2.By not using GetComponentsInChildern

```
foreach(Transform t in parent){
   // add Colliders
}
```

Reference:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/495079/how-to-get-first-depth-child-components-of-a-paren.html

Comment: And what collider should I add to the gameobjects ? Mesh Collider or maybe Box Collider ? Since there are a lot of gameobjects I want to add to them automatic a collider to prevent from the player walk through them. But not sure what type of collider to add.